# pgr_nodeNetwork doesnt put nodes on every intersection

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, network

I used the osmnx python package to get OSM roads network.
I intended to use pgr_createTopology to have a correct network in order to use other pgrounting functions.

However my data from osm is not rightly noded so i tried pgr_nodeNetwork first.

Most of the ouput is correctly noded but I have some wrong cases.
I extract a small sample to test some solutions and show you my problem.

I started with 2 roads, the orange one and the green one.
I expected pgr_nodeNetwork  output to add nodes on the black points I draw on the image.
So I was supposed to get 5 linestrings at the end. The full orange one and the green one split in 4 parts.

[image: My starting data]

But instead I get only 3 parts on the output.

[image: My output]

I tried different tolerance, different SRID et I tried to ST_Dump my geom before using pgr_nodeNetwork. Nothing change.

My pgrounting version is 3.1.3.

I do not understand what's wrong. I'm not even sure now if the output is wrong or if I do not understand what pgr_nodeNetwork is supposed to do.